# Modular arithmetic with coprime integers

Tags: number-theory

Given $a<b$ that are coprime to each other and any number $c<b$, how can I compute $d<b$ such that $d\cdot a\equiv c\mod b$?

Comment: use Euclid's Algorithm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(a,b)=1$ you can use the Euclidean algorithm to find integers $x,y$ with $ax+by=1$.

Then note that you have $cax+cby=c$

If $cx = pb+d$ with $0\leq d \lt b$ then $(pb+d)a+cby=c$ so that $$da+(pa+cy)b=c$$ and $d$ is the number you want.